# How to remove the Day field from the Date drop down?

Tags: webforms

on this page http://dev.amnesty.io1developer.com/donate-now
under the section of the Credit card,I want to remove from the date the Day field.
It is a webform.How to achieve this?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if there is no validation on the form you could hide it with CSS. 
Otherwise you can use a [hook_form_alter](http://drupal.org/node/368776)

Comment: How to use the hook_form_alter please for this element?

Comment: What is the ID of my form and what should I write on hook_form_alter?

Comment: you inspect the HTML for the form element names. Or use this the code snippet shown here: http://drupal.org/node/651106